# Why does my laptop keyboard show up as Standard PS/2 Keyboard or HID Keyboard Device in Windows Device Manager, even though I don't have either?

Tags: keyboard, device-manager

Why does the Windows device manager show my laptop keyboard as a Standard PS/2 Keyboard on one laptop and as a HID Keyboard Device on the other, even though I already know that it is only connected via a ribbon cable directly to the motherboard and none of the doesn't it use the interfaces mentioned above? Is this perhaps a mistake?

Comment: Keyboard drivers are pretty fundamental. You don't want to have to use a nonstandard keyboard driver to install the OS if you can help it. So you are really best off making the connection act like one of the three well-known keyboards on the system bus. Which means that's what Windows will think it is.

Comment: Does the keyboard work fully when it shows up as Standard PS/2 Keyboard or HID Keyboard Device in Windows Device Manager, whether or not you have either? Does it work, or not?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin yes it fully works

Answer (score 29):

PS/2 and USB are protocols that mandate *external* connectors. That doesn't mean that they cannot use whatever connector they want *inside* a computer.

There is no reason for them to use those connectors within a laptop, but there are definitely convenience reasons to use the communications *protocol* such as the electrical signalling and communications methods within a device. There may be an off-the-shelf keyboard (or one that they have already designed) that uses one protocol or another. They may already have drivers that they know works for one device or another within the laptop that can talk to whatever keyboard they have.

Just because there is a ribbon cable does not mandate any given protocol or connector type either. All you need to do is be aware of the general design rules and signal integrity requirements for that electrical signal. I've personally designed ribbon cables that run USB, Ethernet and and other signals and never used a "standard" USB or RJ-45 socket.

In your case you simply have one device that talks PS/2 at your keyboard, and another that uses USB instead. There is nothing more magical than that.

Comment: On top of that, HID can be carried over things other than USB – touchpads in particular often speak HID over I2C or SMBus. (Though a standard laptop still has many other things connected over internal USB, such as the webcam, the fingerprint reader, the WWAN modem...)

Comment: @user1686 indeed, from what I can tell the Surface Pro line have the detachable keyboard appear to the OS as a USB device, but the actual external pins use some kind of proprietary I2C like interface. It is likely a microcontroller doing some kind of level shifting and/or protocol handling.

Comment: To the OP: a fun fact: many Lenovo Thinkpads have a touchpad with three "hard" buttons, which looks like a single device, but in fact the touchpad is a USB-connected thing w/o any buttons, and the buttons "belong" to a PS/2-connected "mouse" where the pointing part is that red "joystick" stuck in between the keyboard buttons :-)

Answer (score 14):

No, it’s absolutely correct. The information there is not talking about the physical connection, but the *protocol* being used to communicate with the device.

The original PS/2 connection for keyboards and mice was designed to use a specific physical connector, but that’s not really part of the protocol those devices use to communicate, just like how copper Ethernet specifies a particular connector, but that connector has nothing to do with what is actually sent over the wire. The PS/2 *protocol* is still widely used in keyboards in laptops over a different type of internal connection because it’s more energy efficient than USB for keyboard usage, and it’s trivial to get it working with a modern operating system (literally just have *something* present essentially the same command interface that the original PC/AT keyboard controller did, which is actually pretty easy).

In a similar manner, HID is a specific protocol that actually technically has *no* external connector defined for it. You can think of it kind of like TCP, it doesn’t care much what the lower layer is as long as it behaves in certain ways (namely, provides framing and in-order delivery of data). It’s widely used for USB input devices (this was where it originated), but is also used for Bluetooth input devices, may be run over I²C, SPI, or some other generic serial bus if a purely internal connection is needed, and apparently there’s even support for running it over ZigBee wireless networks. In most cases, the touchpad in a laptop is a HID device connected over either a hard-wired USB connection, or an I²C connection, with this design choice being made because the PS/2 protocol quite simply doesn’t support a lot of the functionality needed to provide a good touchpad.

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard needs to work out of the box in almost all situations, because without a working keyboard it's rather hard to complete the installation of an operating syste or to fix the problem of not having a working keyboard. This applies both when the firmware/bios is in control of the hardware, and after the operating system takes over control of the hardware. The same applies to some extent without a working mouse, but if you know what you are doing it was usually easier to deal with a keyboard and no mouse than a mouse and no keyboard.

The result is that the standard interface for keyboards on PCs stayed much the same from the introduction of the PC/AT in 1985 to the switch to USB in the 2000s. The IBM PS/2 changed the connector and the new connector was eventually adopted by clones, though there was a long period when both were in use, but as far as I know both the electrical interface and the logical interface stayed the same. The PS/2 also added a mouse interface that was electrically similar to the keyboard interface.

Laptops had a more complex keyboard and mouse situation, they would have an internal keyboard, an internal pointing device (touchpad, trackball or trackpoint) and count often support an external keyboard, an external mouse or both on a splitter, but they still needed to look sufficiently like standard keyboards and mice that someone could boot and install an operating system suceefully. Combining internal and external signals, and detecting what was plugged into the combo PS/2 port would have to be handled by firmware in the laptop's keyboard controller.

USB was first introduced in 1996 but it took a while to find it's feet. There was a version of windows 95 with USB support, but in my experiance it was viritually unusable due to lack of perphiheral drivers.

Windows 98 was better but still problematic, I remember plugging USB keyboards and mice into windows 98 boxes, and they worked fine once you got past the "found new hardware" wizard but without a working keyboard or mouse there was no way to get past the found new hardware wizard. Also bios's from that era generally did not understand USB keyboards or mice, so you couldn't use them at the BIOS or bootloader screens.

The situation improved in the 2000s, windows 2000 would load drivers for USB keyboards and mice without needing user interaction and more BIOS's got USB support.

So that brings us to where we are today, if you as a hardware designer want to make a keyboard that will work out of the box almost everywhere, the safe options are to either make it look like a traditional PC keyboard, or make it look like a USB HID keyboard.